# Displaying or aligning to End of Month, in X-Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an "areasplinerange" type of chart with a dates across the x-axis. 
I am trying to figure out how to align/display or default to, the LAST DAY OF THE MONTH or end of month as the label for tickmarks.

The data itself is there - meaning that dates are sent to the chart but the marker is coming in RIGHT before the beginning of the last month. Hopefully this image will better show what I am talking about. If you have any thoughts or suggestions about this your info would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Example of the issue where the tickmarka are mis-aligned with the actual date on which we receive the data - which comes in at *End of Month* intervals.]

Comment: Add the code of the Highcharts part.

Comment: I'm sorry - I actually haven't figured out how to extract the chart from the application in which it lives. I'm sorry - I can post parts of the config if that helps but in terms of setting up a jsfiddle - that's something I am actively pursuing. Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: You can define your own ticks with [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) or [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner) - so you can define the tick position to be the last day of the month

Comment: By default, the axis ticks align at the beginning of the period (first hour of the day, first day of the week, first month of the year, etc.). The will not make any attempt to align ticks with data points (nor should it). The solution is what @morganfree mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this jsFiddle. Hope it helps what you are trying to do. You can change the date on X-axis accordingly to your need.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sourov00/shhy584f/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average fruit consumption during one year'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && 
Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            '31-01-17',
            '28-02-17',
            '31-03-17',
            '30-04-17',
            '31-05-17',
            '30-06-17',
            '31-07-17',
            '31-08-17',
            '30-09-17',
            '31-10-17',
            '30-11-17',
            '31-12-17'
        ],
        plotBands: [{ // visualize the year-end
            from: 4.5,
            to: 6.5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit units'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' units'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Mango',
        data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12, 6, 4, 8, 11, 14]
    }, {
        name: 'Apple',
        data: [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 8, 5, 9]
    }]
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. The thing is - where you've defined the dates as a categories chart - but it is actually a datetime series I'm working with. The dates are "as of" dates coming from the database. The numbers are reported to the app on the last day of the month. And so, what I'm trying to do involves making sure the crosshair comes down directly over the tickmarks, and if you hover over a part of the areaspline BEFORE the tick mark, you'd see data pertaining to the data BEFORE the month marked by the tickmark. So in the example image from earlier

Comment: I am working with a different type of chart. In my case the chart is an areasplinerange and the x-axis contains month+year info coming from the database.
And about the data, the dates are "as of" dates and the numbers are reported to the app on the last day of the month. So, what I'm trying to do involves making sure the crosshair comes down directly over the tickmarks.

Comment: Hi, can you please create a JSFiddle, so that I can look into the code that you are working along with some relevant sample data? @user3726504